# Displaying null locations using CARTO Builder?

Tags: carto

I'm using CARTO to display locations of conference. Some of the conferences were "teleconference" so they don't have an actual location.

Is it possible to display them on the map with the annotation "teleconference" somewhere?

And is it possible to do so in a time-series animated map?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. I recommend having a look at [this tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) in order to understand how this Q/A works. Although I am going to answer you, next time it is a good practice to go through [CARTO guides](https://carto.com/learn/guides) and explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can show them. Go to the original dataset and change `the_geom` column giving them some coordinates. This is a query that you can apply to geolocate them on [*Null Island*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island):

```
UPDATE
  dataset_name
SET
  the_geom = cdb_latlng(0,0)
WHERE  the_geom IS NULL
```

Alternatively, you can add a column, populate them with a city for those "teleconferences" and then [apply BUILDER `Goreferencing` analysis](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/convert-text-into-city-and-admin-region-geometries). You can add popups or labels to show the annotations. Finally, if you have a date or numeric column you can animated your layer [following this guide](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/animating-maps-with-point-data).